# Jetty and Oracle Configuration

Tags: java, oracle, jetty, oracle-xe

I am trying to setup my web application development environment in IntelliJ with Jetty 7.x
I am using an instance of Oracle XE v10.2

Question -

Currently I can deploy my web application successfully using Tomcat 7.
To do so I build my WAR then copy it over to my /webapps directory in Tomcat.
Then I issue the following command -

```
> catalina.bat jpda start
```

As my web application is being deployed exploded etc... it reads my User home directory where I have several XML files where I specify database configuration settings.  Yes, I'm using a Windows machine to do my development.

I assumed that these config file settings are statically read from the same location no matter type of web server I deploying with.  Apparently not!
Jetty - when it deploys it is pulling my project's default settings and attempting to connect to non-existant MySQL DB.  ughhh....

Where do I specifically tell Jetty about my local instance of Oracle XE and pass it the username, url and password parameters?
I've seen this being done in the jetty.xml file, but I tried that and it didn't work.

Any suggestions.

In case somebody needs the stack trace of my web-app puking -

```
    2012-12-04 13:21:05,939 [Scanner-2] u:/d: 
    INFO: org.kuali.rice.ksb.messaging.quartz.KSBSchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
  java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:184)
at org.kuali.rice.core.database.RiceXADataSource.getConnection(RiceXADataSource.java:54)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardPooledConnection.<init>(StandardPooledConnection.java:65)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXAConnection.<init>(StandardXAConnection.java:81)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXADataSource.getXAConnection(StandardXADataSource.java:110)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardXAPoolDataSource.create(StandardXAPoolDataSource.java:159)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.GenericPool.getFromPool(GenericPool.java:251)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.GenericPool.checkOut(GenericPool.java:357)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardPoolDataSource.getConnection(StandardPoolDataSource.java:194)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardPoolDataSource.getConnection(StandardPoolDataSource.java:164)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore$2.getConnection(LocalDataSourceJobStore.java:125)
at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:112)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:164)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3070)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3713)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:3700)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:570)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:449)
at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:146)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.startScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:627)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:487)
at org.kuali.rice.ksb.messaging.quartz.KSBSchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(KSBSchedulerFactoryBean.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:105)
at org.kuali.rice.core.resourceloader.SpringResourceLoader.start(SpringResourceLoader.java:76)
at org.kuali.rice.core.resourceloader.ResourceLoaderContainer.start(ResourceLoaderContainer.java:54)
at org.kuali.rice.core.resourceloader.BaseResourceLoader.start(BaseResourceLoader.java:102)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurerBase.loadSpringContext(RiceConfigurerBase.java:152)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurerBase.initializeResourceLoaders(RiceConfigurerBase.java:115)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurerBase.start(RiceConfigurerBase.java:96)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurer.start(RiceConfigurer.java:90)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurerBase.afterPropertiesSet(RiceConfigurerBase.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:947)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:701)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.kuali.rice.student.core.web.listener.RiceContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(RiceContextLoaderListener.java:78)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:740)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:353)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

And the stack repeats several times...

Answer (score 0):

For a non-pooling Oracle data source, you need to edit the `jetty.xml` or `WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml` with a Data source entry like below-

```
<New id="DSTest" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
    <Arg>
     <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource">
                 <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</Set>
                 <Set name="User">user</Set>
                 <Set name="Password">pass</Set>     
     </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

Comment: The 2nd Arg value you are using jdbc/DSTest.  Does it matter what I call that?  Another words, can I call it whatever I want?

Comment: Yes it's just an id. You can name it whatever you want.

Comment: I tried creating a jetty-env.xml file and placing that in my webapp's WEB-INF directory, but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you do as per this? Is the XML formatted correctly?- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/jetty-env.xml